# mono : Is remote debugging possible with monodevelop?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop

mono : Is remote debugging possible with monodevelop? I want to remote debug a console application running on a remote RHEL server with monodevelop installed on CentOS development machine. Is this possible with monodevelop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could actually be done with the [Soft Debugger](http://www.mono-project.com/Soft_Debugger).

Comment: @Supercheetah, Any post or doc where it shows how to setup remote debugging session with soft debugger?

Comment: I am interested in a "how to" too. Did you get it running?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864548/debugging-mono-applications-directly-on-arm-target

Answer (score 0):

Currently, no.  This is not possible.  I have heard the MonoDevelop team mention they would like this feature in the future, but I do not believe they have a schedule yet for when they will get to it.

Answer (score 0):

The new Soft Debugger and the MD addin do support remote debugging but there's no way to set up the debugger session from within MD (except for iPhone apps).

Also, despite its name, the MeeGo addin supports remotely running and debugging apps on any GDM-based Linux machine over SSH. It could easily be modified to support machines without X, or running different project types.

http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/monodevelop/extras/MonoDevelop.MeeGo/README.txt