# Debugging mono applications directly on ARM target

Tags: debugging, mono, arm, monodevelop, beagleboard

I've recently installed Mono on a BeagleBone embedded ARM device, looking to connect a Kinnect sensor by USB and control it with C#/Mono

I'm wondering, does Mono (I'm using MonoDevelop but I guess this question also applies to VS) allow you to develop locally and then debug the code against a remote target? If so how can this be accomplished?

I've heard that the Soft Debugger might be what I need but after poking around in the configuration and having a look at the docs I can't find what I need....

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Monodevelop can debug remote targets if you have networking going. before launching monodevelop you need to set the environment variable:

```
MONODEVELOP_SDB_TEST=1
```

Then when you launch MD you'll have "Custom Mono Soft Debugger" as a "Debug With" option.

On the remote host, launch your debug target like so (I'm assuming it has a shell):

```
mono --debug \
--debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:12345,server=y \
myprogram.exe
```

In Mono develop, set your breakpoints and then input the IP address of your target machine and the port number above and click Connect. That should break into the debugger remotely.