# Connect Xamarin to Virtual Box

Tags: c#, linux, mono, xamarin, virtualbox

I want to port my C#-Code to linux, so i have to debug under Mono.
Therefore i would use a VM Box with Linux OS and conect the Xamarin Studio, that runs under Windows, to the Box to debug on it with Mono.

Is it possible to connect my Xamarin Studio to the Oracle VM Virtual Box?
I tried it several times but the debugger didn't Start in 10 minutes. If i closed Xamarin during this starting process there was a this Message: Couldn't connect to Debugger.

If you have an other(easier) way to debug with Windows under Mono i am openminded for everything.

Comment: I thought you had to connect to a real mac for compilation due to licencing? v interested to hear if this is possible.

Comment: @Ewan, I don't think PvtSchneewitchen is talking about debugging a mobile app. I think it's just a library or something. Mono can of course be used for other things than Xamarin! :) Xamarin Studio doesn't run in Linux I believe, but MonoDevelop does. You could use MonoDevelop in your actual Linux environment if you want, instead of trying to attach the Xamarin Studio debugger to a process in your Linux VM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mono : Is remote debugging possible with monodevelop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429906/mono-is-remote-debugging-possible-with-monodevelop)

Answer (score 0):

Does remote debugging still work?

https://ebsteblog.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/remote-debugging-with-monodevelop/

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested: Seems that it is possible. You have to connect the Xamarin to your VM Device and there you star the debugger agent. I couldn't start it yet but theoreticaly it should work. There's the problem:
patrick@patrick-VirtualBox:~$ mono --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,adress=X.X.X.X:12345,server=y OSTest.exe

Cannot open assembly 'OSTest.exe': No such file or directory.
* Assertion at threads.c:391, condition `shutting_down' not met

Stacktrace:

Native stacktrace:

Don't know yet what this means.

Comment: Huh, is the file "OSTest.exe" really there? It seems you are on your home folder (`/home/patrick/` perhaps?), the file might be in a sub directory.